# QGIS: Clip a shapefile based on values in a raster

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, clip

I would like to clip a shapefile based on the values of a raster file beneath it, using QGIS.

The specific context is a shapefile of Local Government Areas overlaid onto a population density raster. I would like to clip the shapefile based on the values of the raster file, e.g. clip the shape Local Government Area to only include areas with a population density above 50 people per square kilometre.

I have found resources on how to do the reverse (clip a raster from a shapefile) but not to clip a shapefile based on raster values.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your raster to shape (`raster -> conversion -> vectorize`), extract only the areas of interest from that shape (`select by attribute`) and then do the clipping.

Where exactly you find these tools depends on your software which you haven't told us yet.

Comment: Thanks, updated the question to include that I am using QGIS software.

Comment: Added the location of the vectorization tool in the menu.